# difference between type=text/javascript and language=javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, types, connection

Basically this is the question. Which is the difference between these two statements:

language

```
<script language="javascript" src="_js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
```

text/javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/calendar/calendar.js"></script>
```

Comment: nothing really. they both run & execute.

Comment: Just because they both currently run and execute doesn't mean they have no difference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per the [HTML 4.01 Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1):

> **type**:
>       This attribute specifies the scripting language of the element's contents and overrides the default scripting language. The scripting language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/javascript"). Authors must supply a value for this attribute. There is no default value for this attribute.
>
> **language**: Deprecated. This attribute specifies the scripting language of the contents of this element. Its value is an identifier for the language, but since these identifiers are not standard, this attribute has been deprecated in favor of type.

Language is generally used to indicate the Javascript *version* that your script requires. Browsers that support the language attribute won't load or run the script if it doesn't support it. About the only use would be if you had critical Javascript functions where you needed workarounds for older browsers.

Comment: Yes. `language` attribute won't specify the scripting language

Answer (score 4):

The `language = JavaScript` suggests that the language formatting and error-checking is to be based on JavaScript standards. The `type = text/javascript` only suggests that the inner contents' formatting will be text, in JavaScript form.

But `language = JavaScript` is deprecated anyway, so don't worry.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html) `language` should have been deprecated or removed :

```
<!ELEMENT SCRIPT - - %Script;          -- script statements -->
<!ATTLIST SCRIPT
  charset     %Charset;      #IMPLIED  -- char encoding of linked resource --
  type        %ContentType;  #REQUIRED -- content type of script language --
  src         %URI;          #IMPLIED  -- URI for an external script --
  defer       (defer)        #IMPLIED  -- UA may defer execution of script --
  >
```